# Spring MVC - Access static resources from outside the application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, glassfish

I have a web application where each of the JSP should be linked to a help pdf file. The files are located outside the web container / application context, but are located within the same server.

I am trying to access them using the spring mvc resource tag but I am still unable to access the pdf file.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the configuration
In a windows env, files are located in
C:\workspace\shared\data\help[all pdfs are here]

I created a jvm argument to access the files -

JVM Argument

```
-Dhelp.dir=/workspace/shared/data/help
```

spring mvc resource tag -

```
<mvc:resources  mapping="/help/*" location="file:/#{systemProperties.help.dir}/"/>
```

I get a 404 error while trying to access the pdf(s)

Glassfish / JDK 1.6

When I click on the Link, the URL generated is -

```
http://localhost:8080/workspace/shared/data/help/abc.pdf
```

My actual web application context is something like this -

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp
```

Comment: You should show the exact URL you type in browser, and the logs corresponding to the request.

Comment: What happens if you type : `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/help/abc.pdf` ?

Comment: I get a 404 error and nothing in the logs

Comment: You should set debug level for the logs and say what are the logs for the request.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a small fix with SpEL syntax,

```
<mvc:resources  mapping="/help/*" location="file:#{systemProperties['help.dir']}"/>
```

and for JVM argument :

```
-Dhelp.dir=/workspace/shared/data/help/
```

with leading and trailing slashes to get it all work

see : http://wordgraphs.com/post/1751/Serving-a-resource-from-outside-the-context-root-in-Spring-MVC
and [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based)

Comment: I have seen this link already. I windows, it makes sense to add c:\ but how about in unix or linux.

Comment: What if this is a linux server?

Comment: @JAGAMOT answer is edited, `file:/absolute/path/to/the/resource/folder/` should work for both linux and windows, also I just figured out you are using wrong syntax for SpEL and an extra leading slash in your JVM argument.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post earlier, even after I made the above adjustments, I see the link getting rendered as  -http://localhost:8080/workspace/shared/data/help/abc.pdf - and when I click I get a 404.

Comment: @JAGAMOT based on your example it was mapped to `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/help/abc.pdf`, you are using location path instead of url mapping pattern, also are you sure you are using absolute path for file location, this means location should be `/home/dir/to/resouces/folder/`.